# iOS: Is [UIApplication schedulelocalnotification] and related local notification manipulating methods thread safe?

Tags: ios

My App sometimes need to schedule almost 64 local notifications, which will block my main thread for almost 1 seconde on iPhone4.
I want to do this on a separated thread, is these local notification manipulating methods of `UIApplcation` thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont think so as the docs dont explicitly state it and UIKit in general in large parts isnt thread safe

but it would be worth a try :D the main thread is only a dispatch_async away ;)

--- maybe it would be an option to schedule them individually and run the main loop in between

Answer (score -1):

There are two things in play, thread safety and calling UIKit from background threads. Some UIKit code doesn’t like to be called from a background thread at all and will throw an exception if you attempt to do so (like setting a new content for a `UITextView`). In other words, there’s something like this in the code:

```
NSParameterAssert([NSThread isMainThread],
    @"This method must be called from the main thread.");
```

Then comes the thread safety, ie. if the code can be called from a background thread, it might still be written in a way that may result in a bug when you do so:

```
- (void) doA {
    for (id item in allItemsArray) {
        // do something
    }
}

- (void) doB {
    [allItemsArray addObject:@"foo"];
}
```

Now if one thread calls `-doA` and another thread calls `-doB` in the meantime, your app would crash with an exception because you changed the `allItemsArray` while enumerating it.

So the first question is if the notification methods can be called on a background thread. I’d say they can. In that case you can simply schedule all your notification from a background queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (int i=0; i<64; i++) {
        // schedule notification
    }
});
```

You don’t need to care about thread safety, unless there’s another part of your app scheduling other local notifications in the meantime. If there is, you can either create a separate queue to serialize all the notification calling code, or you have to be sure that the methods are thread-safe indeed (in which case I have no authoritative resource to offer).

Comment: In my opinion the best way to reason about thread safety is write the code in a way that doesn’t require you to.

Comment: using thread confinement would incur a lot of change to my code TOT